# pangestures interactive like mail app in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9, gestures

I want to give support for iOS 8 and above like `tableview` row actions with animations like the mail app. I have added the pan gesture to the cell and trying to stop the cell from moving up and down while panning the cell, and how to make it interactive like the iOS mail app.

Any help is really appreciated thanks in advance.

I Am handling the gestures in changed state. I have handled in the delegate -- `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and its helped in stop panning the cell only in beginning. after starting to pan the cell was able to move up and down.func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

```
    guard let panRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer else {
       return false
    }


    let velocity  = panRecognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
    if abs(velocity.y) > abs(velocity.x) {
        print("false")
        return false
    }
      print("true")
        return true
}
This is handled in selector method 
    else if(gesture.state == .changed){
                print("ended")
                let velocity  = gesture.velocity(in: self.view)
                if (abs(velocity.y) > abs(velocity.x)) {
                    print("panning upward while panning with touch")
                    //gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:(frame?.center.x)!,y:(frame?.center.y)!), in: self.view)
                }else if(abs(velocity.y) < abs(velocity.x)) {
                    print("panning in horizontal direction ")
                    let velocity  = gesture.velocity(in: self.view)
                    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view )
                    gesture.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gesture.view!.center.x + translation.x, y:gesture.view!.center.y + translation.y)
                    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), in: self.view)
                }
            }
```

Comment: i think are you try the `table cells reorderable concept`

Comment: its not reordering ,i want to make tableviewrowactions for older devices and how to make it interactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be changing only your x-coordinate when the panning is more in the x-direction.

Comment: i have tried this ,the problem is i want pan gestures for moving left and right and not for panning up i want to stop it from being panned up /down

Comment: You seem to be updating both x and y coordinates while panning even though you want to pan in only 1 direction.

Comment: thanks it solved the issue ,how to set limit for panning and animate the rowactions like the mail app ,am new to iOS dev

Comment: @ Rakesha Shastri  Thanks

Comment: any  hint  on animations like mail app for custom tableviewrowactions how to achieve that .

Comment: Just google swipe to reveal actions for tableView cell. There are apple delegates and also lots of 3rd party frameworks which achieve this.

Comment: I need to do this give support for older devices and so i cant  use 3 party libraries so i need to come up with my own code .so i need to make custom action button and animate it .hope you have understood my problem if you come across any resources please share and help